# Can't see Mailchimp IP addresses

Tags: mailchimp

I need the IP addresses of Mailchimp to send it to our IT provider but is it correct there aren't any on this page? The link is here: http://mailchimp.com/about/ips/

I've send support mail to the company but with the timezone difference, I can't wait that long...

Thanks in advance!

*update

Why is this voted down? More clear then this is impossible, it's what Mailchimp tells me to do.

My situation:

1) I send e-mails from Mailchimp to my company mailbox
2) Mails are blocked by anti-spam filter of the company
3) Mailchimp tells me here: http://mailchimp.com/about/ips/ that I have to deliver their IP addresses to my IT company
4) There aren't any on the page, so I ask StackOverflow to help me...

Comment: They have multiple IP addresses ( A records ) for their API's, depending on the client, when you log in you'll notice the address bar change to something like `us5.admin.mailchimp.com` - if you lookup the A record for that you'll see there is a CNAME, follow the CNAME and you'll eventually get to an A record for them. - Although i question why your IT department needs their IP address, can't they just wildcard `*.mailchimp.com`

Comment: Because the mails do not come from abc.mailchimp.com but from mydomain.com@mail61.atl51.rsgsv.net (and that last part changes all the time)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mailchimp and not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Mailchimps XML feed of their IP addresses [**Mailchimp IP Address XML Feed**](http://mailchimp.com/about/ips/feed.xml)

```
72.­26.195.64/27
74.­63.47.96/27
173­.231.138.192/27
173­.231.139.0/24
173­.231.176.0/21
173­.231.184.0/21
205­.201.128.0/20
198­.2.128.0/18
```

Updated: **September 2013**

Comment: Superb, weird that they don't include this link onto the ips page.. :/

Comment: yeh that's odd.. oversight on their behalf i think!